# Series expansion of Beta function in Mathematica

Tags: series-expansion

How one should do the series expansion of Beta function $B(x,y)=\frac{\Gamma(x)\Gamma(y)}{\Gamma(x+y)}$ around an arbitrary negative integer let's say $x=-k$ and $y=-l$? I want a symbolic expression of the coefficients of the expansion in terms of $k$ and $l$.

Comment: may be relevant: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3195847/laurent-expansion-of-the-gamma-function-at-negative-integers

Comment: @ydd That is relevant. But I want to avoid knowing all those details. I thought one should be able to directly expand the function around arbitrary points in mathematica.

Answer (score 1):

You can try directly expanding the function.  For example, the first three terms:

```
Series[Beta[w, v], {w, -k, 3}, {v, -l, 3}]
```

That produces a large expression about -k and -l in terms of Gamma and PolyGamma functions.

Comment: Plugging in integer values produces `Indeterminate` coefficient values though:
`Series[Beta[w, v], {w, -k, 1}, {v, -l, 1}] /. {l -> 1, k -> 1}` 
$\left(\text{Indeterminate}+\text{Indeterminate} (v+1)+O\left((v+1)^2\right)\right)+(w+1) \left(\text{Indeterminate}+\text{Indeterminate} (v+1)+O\left((v+1)^2\right)\right)+O\left((w+1)^2\right)$

Comment: @Lexington1776 Doing the series expansion doesn't really work. Even the leading term is not being reproduced by the way you are suggesting.

Comment: @ydd The beta function is singular at those negative integers.  Try doing the expansion directly around -1. Not using the l->1. You will get some coefficients* 1/x+k..